# Travis is not finding pandas installed by conda

Tags: python, pandas, travis-ci, anaconda

It looks like conda changed the default versions it looks for today, because `conda install numpy scipy` does not currently work:

```
$conda create numpy scipy -n test-build-issue3 --dry-run
Error: Unsatisfiable package specifications
Hint: the following combinations of packages create a conflict with the
remaining packages:
  - numpy 1.7*
  - scipy
```

If I give specific versions, I can set up a working environment locally.

```
conda create numpy=1.7.1 scipy=0.13.0 pandas=0.13.0 matplotlib=1.3 PIL -n test-build --dry-run
```

But on Travis, while conda reports having installed and linked pandas, the test suite raises an ImportError:

```
$ nosetests --nologcapture -a '!slow'
E
(...)
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

One example of a complete failed build is [here](https://travis-ci.org/danielballan/trackpy/jobs/18596190).

The test suite was passing fine yesterday. I have lots of experience with Travis but less experience running and debugging conda on it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the folks over at the [anaconda mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/2DNFgwACRkg), this is resolved.

Today, ContinuumIO updated conda, but not miniconda, and this was the cause of my woes. To protect oneself from this situation, add this line to before-install:

```
- conda update --yes conda
```